# In Vue 3, using PrimeVue, is there a way to change the hamburger menu button to a X when clicked?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, primevue

With the Menubar component, the hamburger menu is automatically displayed when shrinking the browser window. However, upon clicking that button, I want to change the icon from pi-bars to pi-times. Is there a way to do this?

I'm not even sure how to access the button within the code. The example at https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/#/menubar doesn't explain it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with CSS. The menu gets the `.p-menubar-mobile-active` class applied when the mobile-mode menu is open, and the icon (`<i>`) is a descendant of the `.p-menubar-button`. Change the icon's `::before` content to `\e90b`, which is the character code for `pi-times`:

```html
<style>
.p-menubar.p-menubar-mobile-active .p-menubar-button i::before {
  content: "\e90b"; /* pi-times icon */
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-primevues-menubars-icon-when-mobile-menu-open-5d9yt2?file=/src/MenubarDemo.vue)